# Walter Rudin's Principle's of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I was perusing WR's Principles of Mathematical Analysis and I came across something strange.

> Let $A= \{ r:r^2<2 \}$ prove there exists an $s$ such that $r<s$.

This is the author's strange solution.

Let $$s=r-\frac{r^2-2}{r+2}=\frac{2r+2}{r+2} (3)$$

$$s^2-2=\frac{2(r^2-2)}{(r+2)^2}   (4)$$

(3) implies $s>r$ and (4) implies $s^2<2$. I don't understand how $s>r$ it seems like $s<r$.

Comment: If you write it $$s = r + \frac{2-r^2}{r+2},$$ does that make $s > r$ easier to see?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes it does.

Comment: use \{ and \} for sets. Are we finding $s$ from $A$? I don't have my copy of POMA to hand to check the actual wording